# File operations not working in relative paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, io, file-not-found

I am working on a python3 app with a fairly simple file structure, but I'm having issues reading a text file in a script, both of which are lower in the file structure than the script calling them. To be absolutely clear, the file structure is as follows:

```
app/
|- cli-script
|- app_core/
   |- dictionary.txt
   |- lib.py
```

`cli-script` calls `lib.py`, and `lib.py` requires `dictionary.txt` to do what I need it to, so it gets opened and read in `lib.py`.

The very basics of `cli-script` looks like this:

```
from app_core import lib
def cli_func():
  x = lib.Lib_Class()
  x.lib_func()
```

The problem area of lib is here:

```
class Lib_Class:
  def __init__(self):
    dictionary = open('dictionary.txt')
```

The problem I'm getting is that while I have this file structure, the lib file can't find the dictionary file, returning a `FileNotFoundError`. I would prefer to only use relative paths for portability reasons, but otherwise I just need to make the solution OS agnostic. Symlinks are a last resort option I've figured out, but I want to avoid it at all costs. What are my options?

Comment: Please show the simplest code that highlights the problem you're having.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it's just a simple `open(dictionary.txt)` call leading to a file not found error

Comment: Please provide the code in `cli-script` that calls `lib.py`, and the code in `lib.py` that accesses the text file. Both in context.

Comment: @blueteeth just edited the post to include code snippits

Comment: I'm surprised that `lib` imports when `app-core` is named as such (with a hyphen), and there is no `__init__.py`. I would expect `app-core` to be called `app_core`, and there to be an empty file `app_core/__init__.py`.

Comment: And how are you calling `cli-script`?

Comment: @blueteeth I can make the file structure more clear if need be, but to keep things simple, I excluded things like `__init__.py`, thinking it was implied. `app-core` isn't actually named as such, my goal was to make naming as clear as possible, but also easily adapted to other poor souls discovering the same issue

Comment: When I recreate your file structure, I get a `SyntaxError` on `from app-core import lib`, because you can't have a hyphen in a package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a Python script, calls involving paths are executed relative to where you run them from, not where the files are actually from.

The `__file__` variable stores the path of the current file (no matter where it is), so relative files will be siblings to that.

In your structure, `__file__` refers to the path `app/app_core/lib.py`, so to create `app/app_core/dictionary.txt`, you need to co up and then down again.

**app/app_core/lib.py**

```
import os.path

class Lib_Class:
  def __init__(self):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dictionary.txt')
    dictionary = open(path)
```

or using `pathlib`

```
path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'dictionary.txt'
```

Comment: This did the trick! I couldn't get pathlib to work tonight, but that's a nonissue considering you gave 2 methods

Answer (score 1):

Because you are expecting the `dictionary.txt` to be present in the same path as your `lib.py` file you can do the following.

Instead of `dictionary = open('dictionary.txt')` use

```
dictionary = open(Path(__file__).parent / 'dictionary.txt')
```

Comment: is `Path` from pathlib or os?

Comment: from `pathlib` . `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: I have also updated the answer it must be `Path(__file__).parent`